# looking for simple file upload component to access xlsx contents programatically?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a simple file upload component to access xlsx contents programatically.  For example, an app user should be able to click a Browse button on a webpage, select a spreadsheet from their filesystem and then click an "Upload" button to upload the file.  I need to be able to add code in my React app that validates that the column names in the xlsx that the user selects for upload are as expected.  For example, something like:

```
if(formCells[0][0].value != "AccountName") //display error on webpage
if(formCells[0][1].value != "AccountNumber") //display error on webpage
etc
```

Then I need to be able to simply loop through the rows to build an array of objects that I can pass to my Express API.  What is the simplest way for me to accomplish this implementation in a React app?  Is there a popular prebuilt React component that I can use for this?

Comment: Short answer is NO. That's too specific. You might find packages that do one of the thing you required. If you need to read/write XLSX files you can use [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)  or [sheetjs](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs)

Comment: wow the xlsx package gets 500k downloads per week.  that's massively popular/proven.  I'll check it out.  thanks for the tip!